# Why does my slide out navigation add margin to my container and body?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, css-transitions

I'm experimenting with css grids and animations. I have this navigation that is included on every page with a PHP statement and it works perfect with my javascript.

However I want my slide out nav to push my container down. I set a transition to add `padding-top`and it does what it's suppose to do accept it adds padding to the container and the body. I tried using margin instead and it does the same thing.

```
/* The navigation transition */
#nav ul {
  background: #3a3a40;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  transition: max-height cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.82, 0.59) 0.4s;
}
#nav .slide {
  max-height: 270px;
}
```

Here is my container css

```
/* The container transition */
    .c-content {
  grid-column: 1/5;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  background: green;
  z-index: -1;
  grid-row: 1/3;
  padding-top: 0;
  transition: padding-top cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.82, 0.59) 0.4s;
}
.transition {
  padding-top: 270px;
}
```

PHP nav include file

```
 /* The PHP include html */
<header id="nav">
  <ul id="ul">
    <div id="nav-grid">
      <a class="nav-box" href="index.php"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a class="nav-box" href="#"><li>Treatments</li></a>
      <a class="nav-box" href="media.php"><li>Media</li></a>
      <a class="nav-box" href="contact.php"><li>Contact</li></a>
    </div>
  </ul>
</header>
  <div class="menu">
    <div id="handle" class="handle" onclick="toggle()">
      <p>Menu</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

JavaScript toggle file

```
var menustate = 0;
function toggle() {
  if (menustate == 0) {
    document.getElementById('ul').classList.add('slide');
    document.getElementById('move').classList.add('transition');
    menustate = 1
  } else if (menustate == 1) {
    document.getElementById('ul').classList.remove('slide');
    document.getElementById('move').classList.remove('transition');
    menustate = 0
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>ESTEBAN</title>
  </head>
  <body class="c-grid">
    <div id="header">
      <?php include_once "includes/header.php" ?>
    </div>

      <section class="c-content" id="move">
        <p>item</p>
      </section>

      <div class="footer">
        <?php include_once "includes/footer.php" ?>
      </div>
      <script src="includes/transitons.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here are some photos of what I'm talking about [before toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8Ulg.png) and [after toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Zms.png). As you can see it looks bad and adds a scroll bar because it is adding height to the body and the container. Its weird I have no clue how to fix it. I just want it to push my page content down.

Comment: I'm sunsure what exactly you're trying to achieve. Your element expands out from where it is currently positioned, so that it occupies space directly below itself. Due to the increase in content, scrolling is expected. What exactly are you trying to change? Do you want to remove the scrolling functionality?

Comment: Simply I want my navigation to push my content down. If you look in my first picture my content and footer aren't very tall but when I push my button instead of it expanding into the body like it should it adds height to my container and for some reason pushes my body down as well. It should really only affect the container elements padding-top